# Capacitors exploding on PWM motor controller

Tags: capacitor, pwm, dc-motor

I'm part of a project in which we are developing a PWM controller for a 24V DC motor.

Our current problem is choosing a capacitor to replace C1, which keeps exploding. We've been running tests at 50Amps which is around the current that will be passing through the motor in normal conditions.

How do we choose the right capacitor in terms of voltage, capacitance, ripple current and ESR?

[image]

The capacitor we currently use is the SAMXON KM series 47uF 63V, with 146mA of ripple current and it is clearly under dimensioned. Here is the the simulation using a PWM signal of 4kHz, 50% duty cycle.

The current exceeds by a lot the maximum the capacitor can take but if I change it for another capacitor with higher capacitance and higher ripple current the problem keeps happening, but with higher currents, which makes sense I think.

[image]

Finally, one last question: Is the voltage change across the terminals of the batteries we see on the graph bad for them? These are lead-acid AGM batteries from Yuasa: https://www.yuasa.co.uk/batteries/industrial/rec-vrla-cyclic-use/rec36-12.html.

Some of the components we use:

- NMOS
  https://www.tme.eu/gb/details/irlb3034pbf/tht-n-channel-transistors/infineon-technologies/
- Schottky Diode
  https://www.tme.eu/gb/details/vt4045bp-m3_4w/tht-schottky-diodes/vishay/
- Capacitor
  http://www.paullinebarger.net/DS/Samxon/Samxon%20%5Bradial%20thru-hole%5D%20KM%20Series.pdf

---

Here is the PCB (older version), PCB layout (current version) and PCB render (current version).

[image: PCB]

[image: PCB layout]

[image: PCB render]

---

Version with multiple caps, same current passing through each one:

[image]

---

Battery and motor setup, during testing. Both motor and batteries positive poles connected to the middle contact in the controller, motor negative connected to the right, battery negative pole connected to the left.
The other motor is connected to a couple of high power resistors to generate load.

[image]

Comment: What is the whole part number for the 47uF cap? Also you have in the sim everything connected to ground, in the real world you will have inductance and resistance for wires so this simulation is not accurate.

Comment: Can I ask what is the *purpose* of the cap?

Comment: Either you remove C1 at all or you use _many_ polymer electrolyte caps in parallel, that can carry the high ripple current as a group

Comment: @Jens removing C1 will push the problem to the power supply, which is probably more expensive to replace.

Comment: Adding more caps in parallel is the solution.  Also, higher voltage caps.  When the motor back EMF gets dumped to the cap, its voltage can go well above the supply rail. Also, these caps should be very close to the driving circuit (FETs?)

Comment: Post a picture of your actual built circuit.

Comment: @user253751 the circuit is not quite complete in the diagram I showed. The cap is there to protect the batteries as well as a voltage regulator connected to those same 24V.

Comment: @Aaron The power supply is a battery

Comment: @Aaron pictures posted. I will try to add more caps in the simulation now. What rating should they be? Higher voltage than the 63V of the current caps? Same capacitance?

Comment: @Aaron: I'm just thinking, the DC losses are around 20W at full on per battery, AC losses are maximum at 50% duty, but DC loss is half then. I guess AC losses are lower than the reduced DC loss. Can you help me thinking this though? I'm somehow blocked

Comment: @VoltageSpike The cap part number should be EKM476M1Jx11RR (I don't know x). But it is the only cap with 47uF and 63V on the datasheet I linked. Also, can you tell me what should be different in a circuit powered by a battery vs a circuit powered by a normal PSU?

Comment: @Aaron adding more caps in parallel just works as a bigger capacitor so there is more current being drawn. The current flowing through each capacitor stays the same

Comment: Adding more caps in parallel reduces the effective ESR, like parallel resistors.  This also reduces the current in each, thus the heat in each.

Comment: @Aaron just added more caps, check the edit, current through each stays the same

Comment: Please post a photo showing the wiring between the batteries and controller.

Comment: @BruceAbbott i've posted it

Comment: @JoãoCoelho If you push alt and click on a component after running a simulation you can see the power through it.

Answer (score 2):

As per the attached waveforms, peak-to-peak ripple current through the capacitor is in the range of 3-3.2A and the selected capacitor's ripple current rating is 146mA.

As per the datasheet, it is a general-purpose capacitor whose ESR value will be significant for the actual p-p ripple current. The explosion might be the result of I^2R losses on the capacitor.

As per calculation, the capacitor value should be more than 350uF for 4kHz and 50% duty cycle operation. Here we consider 2% voltage ripple.

Try increasing capacitor value and changing the capacitor type from electrolytic to MKP which provides more ruggedness to the system.

The ripple on the battery voltage may occur due to the parasitic inductance of the traces and it will increase if the distance is more. So place the caps close to reduce track inductance.

For further clarification, kindly contact us on Infineon Developer Community.
https://community.infineon.com/

Comment: SuhasB888 - Hi, From the wording in your answer "kindly contact us..." it seems you might be representing Infineon. If so, please note the rule about [promotion](/help/promotion) here. You must fully disclose any affiliation with anything you mention or link (i.e. anything you promote) in a post here. If this applies to you, please [edit] your post and add: "Disclosure: I work for Infineon" (or whatever explains your apparent promotion here). Please also read the [tour] and [help] to see the main site rules. Thanks.